# How the computer knows "Recommended for You"?

Tags: algorithm

Recently, I found several web site have something like : "Recommended for You", for example youtube, or facebook, the web site can study my using behavior, and recommend some content for me... ...I would like to know how they analysis this information? Is there any Algorithm to do so? Thank you.

Comment: Netflix offered a 1 million dollar prize to improve their algorithm, so obviously a good algorithm isn't cheap.  http://www.netflixprize.com/

Comment: Does the computer ever know what is recommended? Its the application that knows.

Comment: @Kangkan: you're getting awfully technical, on a slippery road... Does the application effectively _knows_? Does the application exist outside of the computer?

Comment: Do you have a doghouse? If so, statistically, you probably have a dog. If you have a dog, there's a good chance you have kids. If you have kids, I'm willing to bet you've got a wife. If you've got a wife, I'm willing to bet you're straight. What's that? you don't have a doghouse? Gay.

Comment: ^Not meant to offend...just a funny way of using broad statistics to determine "facts" on somebody, and how they can go awry.

Comment: If you wanted to implement something simple, you could use keywords/tags and base it around that.  If you built your own basic YouTube, you could track that a user watched x number of videos with the tag "justin-bieber".  From that, you can have your recommendation engine pull the most popular videos with the "justin-bieber" tag.  Add a like/hate button too, so that your user (providing he/she is sane) can click the "hate" button on the recommended video with the "justin-bieber" tag and never see anything related to that little <expletive> in their recommended views again!

Comment: @Rownage: Whether you meant to offend or not, it is still offensive in the context you used it. You meant it to be funny as you said, so that in itself is why it is offensive. Many examples could have been used, such as an example with types of animals, to prove your point. Please refrain from using words that you clearly already know could offend.. (you attempted a disclaimer..) Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazon and Netflix (among others) use a technique called [Collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) to suggest things you might like based on the likes/dislikes of others who have made purchases and selections similar to yours.

Comment: Which sometimes does weird things.  Amazon once correlated a book, a CD and a computer accessory that I'd bought, and recommeded a DVD (I was interested in it though....)

Comment: @James Curran: Between CS texts and comic books Amazon has me pretty accurately pegged as a giant nerd.  Netflix is more interesting because I share a queue with my wife.  I like sci-fi a lot, but she doesn't.  After she watched *Free Willy* recently, I was amused to see it recommend *Star Trek IV*.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any Algorithm to do so?

Yes

Comment: I could have never been this prompt. :)

Comment: Pretty worthless answer, even if it's slightly funny/honest.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One fairly common one is to look at things you've selected in the past, find other people who've made those selections, then find the other selections most common among those other people, and guess that you're likely to be interested in those as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yup there are lots of algorithms. Things such as k-nearest neighbor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm.

Here is a pretty good book on the subject that covers making these sorts of systems along with others: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596529325?ie=UTF8&tag=ianburriscom-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0596529325](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325).

Answer (score 1):

It's generally done by matching you with other users who have similar usage history / profile and then recommending other things that they've purhased/watched/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "recommendation algorithm" yields lots of papers. Most algorithms incorporate "machine learning" algorithms to determine groups of things (comedy movies, books on gardening, orchestral music, etc.). Your matching with those groups yields recommendations. Some companies use humans to classify things, too.

Answer (score 0):

Such an algorithm is going to vary wildly from company to company.  In many cases, it analyzes some combination of your search history, purchase history, physical location, and other factors.  It probably will also compare purchases/searches amongst other people to find what those people have purchased/searched for, and recommend some of those products to you.

There are probably hundreds of these algorithms out there, but I doubt you can use any of them (that are actually good).  Probably you are better off figuring it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can categorize your contents (i.e. by tagging or content analysis), you can also categorize your users and their preferences.

For example: you have a video portal with 5 million videos .. 1 mio of them are tagged `mostly red`. If 80% of all videos watched by a user (who is defined by an IP, a persistent user account, ...) are tagged `mostly red`, you might want to recommend even more red videos to him. You might want to refine your recommendations by looking at his further actions: does he like your recommendations -- if so, why not give him even more, if not, try the second-best guess, maybe he's not looking for color, but for the background music ...

There's no absolute algorithm to do it, but all implementations will go into a similar direction. It's always basing on observing users, which scares me from time to time :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's whole lot of algorithms tackling the issue: [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system). It's a Machine Learning domain problem. Computer's can be learned using two main techniques: classification and clustering. They require some datasets as input. If the dataset is informative (really holds some useful patterns) than those ML techniques can dig most of it.

Clustering could be best to use for this kind of problem. It's main usage is to find similarities among points in provided dataset. If the points are, e.g. your search history, they can be grouped together to form certain clusters. If Your search history closely relates to another, a hint can be given - picking links that are most similar to Your's.

The same comes with book recommendations - it's obvious what dataset they use: "Other people who bought this product also bought Product A, Product B,...". The key here is to match your profile to other's and use the most similar to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

The computer retrieves information from the human brain with complex memory scan process, sorts it accordingly and outputs results based on what you have experienced in your life so far.